# Position of 了in 发生了什么事 vs 发生什么事了

Tags: grammar

Compare the position of 了 in the following sentences:

```
发生了什么事？
What happened?

我想知道他发生什么事了。
I wonder what has happened to her.
```

Can you explain what the difference is in the positions of the 了?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 发生了什么事 VS 发生什么事了

There isn't essential difference between them. They mean the same and are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

发生了什么事 more refers to an action/occurance which have/had happened. Finished doing/being smth
Like
我吃了一个苹果 (I ate the apple and now it doesnt exist)
While,
发生什么事了points that the situation is changed.
Like
他现在是一位老师了。he is a teacher now (before, he wasn't a teacher)
我不吃巧克力了。I don't eat chocolate (before, I used to eat, now, situation is changed, I don't eat chocolate)

Answer (score 0):

Actually no difference. You can use these two usages at will.
But I want to point out a small problem.
“我想知道他发生什么事了。” should be translated as “I wonder what has happened to him.”
"他" means "he/him" and “她” means "she/her".